# Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style' (XamlParseException Unhandled:Windows Phone SDK)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm developing a simple app for Windows Phone using SDK 7.1, and I'm getting the error "

> XamlParseException, Failed to assign to property
>   'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style' because the type
>   'System.Windows.Media.Color' cannot be assigned to the type
>   'System.Windows.Style'."

while trying to Run the application on Windows Phone Emulator. I'm new to WP and I'd really appreciate it if a quick reply's given..

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Show us the line 22 of MainPage.xaml

Comment: [link](http://i45.tinypic.com/205oxeg.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in Line 22 of MainPage.xaml.

As the exception tells us: You tried to set the `Color` to the `UIElement's` Style property.

Try to change `Style` to `Background`.

```
<TextBlock Background="{StaticResource PhoneBorderColor}">
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but where am i supposed to type '<TextBlock Background="{StaticResource PhoneBorderColor}">'  ?

Comment: In line 22 you have a textblock. Just change Style to Background.

Comment: Damn, a yet-another error..

[Screenshot](http://i45.tinypic.com/10ynmz7.jpg)
'property background not found in textblock'
(P.S: thanks for ur continued help, pls keep helping me, m rly new to WP dev. n thanks)

Comment: Ok, my misstake, there is no backgrowd property in textblock. what do you want to achieve?

Comment: ok, just remove Style="{StaticResource PhoneBorderColor}" from the code. Does it work?

Comment: I removed that as well as another 'Style' command at line 26...
now the app is showing up in the emulator... I'll let you know here in case there's any other issue now :) thanks :)
btw, what do u think was the problem?

Comment: The problem was: Style and Color has different types. So, you can't set Color to Style property. If you'll get an other problem- make a new question here. That will help other guy to answer it.

Answer (score -1):

I have to share my experience abt this problem....
I was also face this exception when I code first apps
You just look on

```
 shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" Name="MiniBrowser">
```

this code in your apps..
You should making nameing apps and clearly so it dosent give name conflict
and just go on this link it will more help full....
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402526(v=vs.105).aspx